# VBA code to copy paste data from multiple worksheets to a single consolidated worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy data from multiple worksheets and consolidate them into my master file. My code works fine when there is data in the worrksheets. However, when there is no data on the worksheet, the copied data will be my headers instead. Could anyone help me to write a code into my existing code where no data will be copied if the worksheet has no data? Thank you so much

```
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

Sheets("SEA-Weekly New Opp").Select
Range("A4:N1000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents

Workbooks.Open "Z:\SFDC Reporting\MSIA(PENANG,ESTEROL,TAMPOI) Reporting Template.xlsm", 
Password:="Mingsee"

Set wsCopy = Workbooks("MSIA(PENANG,ESTEROL,TAMPOI) Reporting Template.xlsm").Worksheets("New Opps")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("CY All OPS APAC WORKING FILE MACRO WORKING FILE - 
Copy.xlsm").Worksheets("SEA-Weekly New Opp")


lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row



wsCopy.Range("A2:N" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A4")

Workbooks("MSIA(PENANG,ESTEROL,TAMPOI) Reporting Template.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True

Workbooks.Open "Z:\SFDC Reporting\MSIA(Plentong) Reporting Template.xlsm", Password:="Phyllis"



Set wsCopy = Workbooks("MSIA(Plentong) Reporting Template.xlsm").Worksheets("New Opps")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("CY All OPS APAC WORKING FILE MACRO WORKING FILE - 
Copy.xlsm").Worksheets("SEA-Weekly New Opp")


lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row


wsCopy.Range("A2:N" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)


Workbooks("MSIA(PLENTONG) Reporting Template.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True

Workbooks.Open "Z:\SFDC Reporting\INDONESIA Reporting Template.xlsm", Password:="Melinda"


Set wsCopy = Workbooks("INDONESIA Reporting Template.xlsm").Worksheets("New Opps")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("CY All OPS APAC WORKING FILE MACRO WORKING FILE - 
Copy.xlsm").Worksheets("SEA-Weekly New Opp")


lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row


wsCopy.Range("A2:N" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)

Workbooks("INDONESIA Reporting Template.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True

Workbooks.Open "Z:\SFDC Reporting\PHILIPPINES Reporting Template.xlsm", Password:="Janet"
excel
```

Comment: Add a line following the first line of your code, `If lCopyLastRow <2 Then Exit Sub`. This is presuming that out of a minimum of 2 rows only one row would contain data.

Comment: The macro stopped running after the first workbook was opened as it had no data, is there anyway to make it continue running for all worksheets

Comment: Modify your question to include the entire procedure and I'll take a look.

Comment: Is the code in the workbook `CY All OPS...`?

Answer (score 0):

### Consolidate Data from Multiple Worksheets

**A Quick Fix**

After each line...

```
lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

... you could use:

```
If lCopyLastRow > 1 Then
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    wsCopy.Range("A2:N" & lCopyLastRow).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
End If

Workbooks("...").Close SaveChanges:=True ' 'False' seems more appropriate!?
```

**An Improvement (Not Tested)**

```
Sub createReport()
    
    ' Destination
    Const dwbName As String = "CY All OPS APAC WORKING FILE MACRO WORKING " _
        & "FILE - Copy.xlsm "
    Const dwsName As String = "SEA-Weekly New Opp"""
    Const dFirst As Long = 4
    ' Source
    Const sPath As String = "Z:\SFDC Reporting\"
    Const swsName As String = "New Opps"
    Dim swbNames As Variant: swbNames = Array( _
        "MSIA(PENANG,ESTEROL,TAMPOI) Reporting Template.xlsm", _
        "MSIA(Plentong) Reporting Template.xlsm", _
        "INDONESIA Reporting Template.xlsm", _
        "PHILIPPINES Reporting Template.xlsm")
    Dim swbPasswords As Variant: swbPasswords = Array( _
        "Mingsee", "Phyllis", "Melinda", "Janet")
    Const sFirst As Long = 2
    ' Both
    Const bCols As String = "A:N"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dCell As Range
    With Workbooks(dwbName).Worksheets(dwsName).Columns(bCols).Rows(dFirst)
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        Set dCell = .Cells(1)
    End With
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sLast As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = LBound(swbNames) To UBound(swbNames)
        Set sws = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=swbNames(n), _
            Password:=swbPasswords(n)).Worksheets(swsName)
        With sws.Columns(bCols)
            sLast = .Columns(1).Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
        If sLast >= sFirst Then
            Set srg = sws.Columns(bCols).Rows(sFirst).Resize(sLast - sFirst + 1)
            srg.Copy dCell
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(srg.Rows.Count)
        End If
        sws.Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next n
                                                      
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```